# WebGL is not supported by your browser - visit https://get.webgl.org for more info Angular, Plotly, optimization: scripts: true

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, plotly, webgl

3d graphics are not displayed when we put the projects:app:architect:build:configurations:production:optimization:scripts - true in angular.json. There are no errors, but we have message instead of our 3d graphic: WebGL is not supported by your browser - visit https://get.webgl.org for more info.                                                              1. Module :

```
import * as PlotlyJS from 'plotly.js-dist-min';
import { PlotlyModule } from 'angular-plotly.js';
```

```
PlotlyModule.plotlyjs = PlotlyJS;
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AnalyticsVisualizationComponent,
    and another
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PlotlyModule,
    and another
  ],
})
```

2. Component:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { PREDICTIONS_MOCK } from '@app/app/shared/mock/predictions.mock';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AnalyticsService } from '@app/app/shared/services/dashboard/analytics.service';
import { Plotly } from 'angular-plotly.js/lib/plotly.interface';
import { LoadingService } from '@app/app/shared/services/app-state/loader.service';
import { finalize, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { PlotlyComponent } from 'angular-plotly.js';
import { Point } from 'plotly.js-dist-min';
import { AppStateService } from '@app/app/shared/services/app-state/app-state.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ContrastService } from '@app/app/shared/services/settings/contrast.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-analytics-visualization',
  templateUrl: './analytics-visualization.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./analytics-visualization.component.scss'],
})
export class AnalyticsVisualizationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('plot', { static: false }) public plot: PlotlyComponent;

  public graph: Plotly.Layout;
  public isActive = false;
  public minScale = 0.8;
  public maxScale = 3.5;
  public maxRadius = 6;
  public minRadius = 1.3;
  public graphName: {};
  public coords: { x: number, y: number, z: number };
  public items = PREDICTIONS_MOCK;

  private _destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _location: Location,
    private _router: Router,
    private _analyticsServices: AnalyticsService,
    private _loadingService: LoadingService,
    private _appStateService: AppStateService,
    private _contrastService: ContrastService,
  ) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this._loadingService.changeLoadingState(true);
    this._analyticsServices.getAnalytics3d_data()
      .pipe(finalize(() => this._loadingService.changeLoadingState(false)))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        const ret = res.replace('[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]',
          '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]');
        this.graphName = JSON.parse(ret);
        this.isActive = true;
        this.onCreateGraph(this.graphName);
      });
    this._subscribeOnAccessibility();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._destroy$.next();
    this._destroy$.complete();
  }

  public onCreateGraph(name: {}): void {
    if (name) {
      this.graph = {
        data: [
          {
            opacity: 0.7,
            color: 'rgba(20, 121, 186, 1)',
            type: 'mesh3d',
            x: name[0].flat(),
            y: name[1].flat(),
            z: name[2].flat(),
          },
        ],
        width: 1000,
        height: 700,
        margin: {
          l: 0,
          r: 0,
          b: 50,
          t: 50,
        },
        scene: {
          camera: {
            eye: { ...this.coords },
          },
          xaxis: {
            title: 'X – Dates',
            gridcolor: this._contrastService.getPropertyValue('--light-black'),
          },
          yaxis: {
            title: 'Y – Maturities',
            gridcolor: this._contrastService.getPropertyValue('--light-black'),
          },
          zaxis: {
            title: 'Z – Spot yields',
            gridcolor: this._contrastService.getPropertyValue('--light-black'),
          },
        },
      };
    }
  }

  public onRelayout(event: { 'scene.camera': { eye: Point } }): void {
    this.coords = { ...event['scene.camera']?.eye };
    const dist = Math.sqrt(this.coords.x ** 2 + this.coords.y ** 2 + this.coords.z ** 2);
    if (dist <= this.maxRadius || dist >= this.minRadius) {
      this._minMaxRelayout(0, event['scene.camera']?.eye);
    }
    if (dist < this.minRadius) {
      this._minMaxRelayout(this.minScale);
    }
    if (dist > this.maxRadius) {
      this._minMaxRelayout(this.maxScale);
    }
  }

  private _minMaxRelayout(count: number, eye?: Point): void {
    this.graph.scene.camera.eye.x = count || eye.x;
    this.graph.scene.camera.eye.y = count || eye.y;
    this.graph.scene.camera.eye.z = count || eye.z;
    this.plot.updatePlot().then();
  }

  private _subscribeOnAccessibility(): void {
    this._appStateService.contrast
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))
      .subscribe(() => this.onCreateGraph(this.graphName));
  }

}
```

3. Template:

```
<div class="c-dashboard__ticket-details">
  <plotly-plot *ngIf="isActive" #plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph" (relayout)="onRelayout($event)"></plotly-plot>
</div>
```

[image]

We tried: connect the library via scripts, enter a method that renders graphics in the method runOutsideAngular(), connected and disconnected zones, exclude the component from our build, add "use hardware acceleration" in browser(Chrome, updated to last version 107.0.5304.89(official) 64 bit, drivers updated too). This all happens only when optimizing the application when in angular.json:

```
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": true,
  "fonts": true
},
```

```
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"namedChunks": false,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,
```

Expect to view 3d graphic with

```
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": true,
  "fonts": true
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same **issue while plotting 3D scatter plots in Angular**. In development mode, everything works fine but on production build it was throwing the "*WebGL is not supported by your browser*" error.

What worked for me was changing the plotly import.

**instead of using the minified version**

```
import * as PlotlyJS from 'plotly.js-dist-min';
```

**used the unminified version and it worked**

```
import * as PlotlyJS from 'plotly.js-dist';
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Development was fine, production gave me "WebGL is not supported" message with plotly 3D surface plot in Angular 15 project.

Disabling `buildOptimizer` in `angular.json` worked for me, but still no clue why the build optimization causes issue.

```json
...
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      ...
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          ...
          "buildOptimizer": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I hope this will help, as I spent several hours to figure it out